# Android NDK - Library not found CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE - how to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: android

I have an Android activity where I'm executing NDK compiled code (command line program) with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommand);
```

and load the needed shared libraries with:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary(myLib);
}
```

but when running my project and printing the output from error stream I get the following error:

```
link_image[1963]:  7520 could not load needed library 'libmyLib.so' for './myCommand'
(load_library[1105]: Library 'libmyLib.so' not found)CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE
```

I assure `libmyLib.so` does exist in my project under `libs/armeabi/` directory and it's copied to my Android device under `/data/data/myProject.path.package/lib/` directory. Owner and group of both executable and library are `system:system` and permissions are ok as well.

When executing the command from adb shell in the beginning I get the same error but then I can set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and it runs ok:

```
./adb shell
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/myProject.path.package/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/data/data/myProject.path.package/myCommand
```

So the question is, how to do that from java Android project?

Note: I'm using Linux, Eclipse + Sequoyah, NDK-r5b, Android 2.3.6 (API 10) on GT-P1010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved: you can use `exec(String prog, String[] envp)`. In my case this was:

```
String[] envp = {"LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/cse.ecg.dcmtk/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myCommand, envp);
```

The issue now is that with `exec()` the process executed can't resolve hostnames (it does from adb shell; Internet permission is set). Any hint about that?